# Error for maven-compiler-plugin in eclipse

Tags: maven-compiler-plugin

[image]

getting error for maven-compiler-pluggin in eclipse
any solution?

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include the `servlet-api-xxx.jar` in your dependencies.

- **Maven**

  ```xml
  <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  ```

Answer (score 1):

As the error says you are missing one class, so you'll need to add the dependency, as is a dependency that will exist on server mark it as provided to indicate maven to use it in compile time but not include it in the generated artifact (provided by deploy environment). Try adding this dependency in your project pom.xml:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Hopes this helps.

Comment: As Giancarlo says, better to use a newest version of artifact.